# (answer package) Preventing hyperlink to missing answer of problem

Tags: hyperref, numbering, links, answers

Code below is helped to get clickable numbers of problems for best navigation between problem and its answer.

An environment `solution` inside other environment `problem` imply the problem has a solution. After clicking link it goes to defined `\hypertarget{solution:#1}{...}`

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage{ntheorem}
\usepackage{answers}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\makeatletter
\newtheoremstyle{problemstyle}%
{\hypertarget{problem:##2}{}\item[\theorem@headerfont{\hyperlink{solution:##2}{##2.}}] }
{\hypertarget{problem:##2}{}\item[\theorem@headerfont{\hyperlink{solution:##2}{##2.}}] (##3)}

\makeatother

\theoremstyle{problemstyle}
\newtheorem{problem}{}
%\renewcommand{\theproblem}{\thechapter.\arabic{problem}}
\Newassociation{solution}{Solution}{answer}
\renewenvironment{Solution}[1]{%
    \par%
    \hypertarget{solution:#1}{\noindent\hyperlink{problem:#1}{\bfseries #1.}}
}{%
    \par%
}

\begin{document}
\Opensolutionfile{answer}[Answers]

\begin{problem}
Problem with solution
\begin{solution}
Solution
\end{solution}
\end{problem}

\begin{problem}
Problem with NO solution
\end{problem}

\Closesolutionfile{answer}
\newpage
\input{Answers}
\end{document}
```

But what if problem has no solution? Then no environment `solution` inside `problem`. But `\hyperlink{solution:##2}{##2.}}` is still here and link to missing target.

**How to prevent hyperlinking, if target is missing?**

Unfortunately, this [solution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/139600/visual-feedback-for-broken-hyperlinks-and-hypertargets) does not work for me, because of `\csname link@#1 \endcsname` `\link@1.` does not allowed in `TeX`.

I have solution. It imply manual marking such tasks (`\begin{problem}[noanswer] ... \end{problem}` ):

```
\newtheoremstyle{problemstyle}%
{\hypertarget{problem:##2}{}\item[\theorem@headerfont{\hyperlink{solution:##2}{##2.}}] }
{
\ifthenelse{\equal{##3}{noanswer}}
{\item[\theorem@headerfont{##2.}]}
{\hypertarget{problem:##2}{}\item[\theorem@headerfont{\hyperlink{solution:##2}{##2.}}] (##3)}
}
```

But this is not true way. I want an automatic check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Unfortunately, this solution does not work for me, because of \csname
>   link@#1 \endcsname \link@1. does not allowed in TeX.

Yes, indeed, but you can get round this using, for example, `\@roman{#1}` to change numbers into roman numerals.

In the following, I've made a few amendments to your code, including:

```
\newtheoremstyle{problemstyle}%
{%
    \hypertarget{problem:\@roman{##2}}{}%
    \ifcsname r@solution\@roman{##2}\endcsname
        \item[\theorem@headerfont{\hyperlink{solution:\@roman{##2}}{##2.}}]
    \else
        \item[\theorem@headerfont{##2}]
    \fi
}
{\hypertarget{problem:\@roman{##2}}{}\item[\theorem@headerfont{\hyperlink{solution:\@roman{##2}}{##2.}}] (##3)}
```

and the corresponding amendment to the `Solution` environment:

```
\label{solution\@roman{#1}}
```

Here's a complete MWE

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage{ntheorem}
\usepackage{answers}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[left]{showlabels}   % <------- remove these lines once you're happy!
\showlabels{hypertarget}        % <------- remove these lines once you're happy!
\showlabels{hyperlink}          % <------- remove these lines once you're happy!
\makeatletter
\newtheoremstyle{problemstyle}%
{%
    \hypertarget{problem:\@roman{##2}}{}%
    \ifcsname r@solution\@roman{##2}\endcsname
        \item[\theorem@headerfont{\hyperlink{solution:\@roman{##2}}{##2.}}]
    \else
        \item[\theorem@headerfont{##2}]
    \fi
}
{\hypertarget{problem:\@roman{##2}}{}\item[\theorem@headerfont{\hyperlink{solution:\@roman{##2}}{##2.}}] (##3)}

\theoremstyle{problemstyle}
\newtheorem{problem}{}
%\renewcommand{\theproblem}{\thechapter.\arabic{problem}}
\Newassociation{solution}{Solution}{answer}
\renewenvironment{Solution}[1]{%
    \par%
    \label{solution\@roman{#1}}%
    \hypertarget{solution:\@roman{#1}}{\noindent\hyperlink{problem:\@roman{#1}}{\bfseries #1.}}
}{%
    \par%
}

\begin{document}
\Opensolutionfile{answer}[Answers]

\begin{problem}
Problem with solution
\begin{solution}
    Solution
\end{solution}
\end{problem}

\begin{problem}
Problem with NO solution
\end{problem}

\Closesolutionfile{answer}
\newpage
\input{Answers}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you! It seems, the `\@roman{...}` does not necessary in you realization,  all work fine without it. Also, a `r@<ref>`became a new knowledge for me.